# how long does it take to crack wpa or wpa2

Tags: wifi

I have a laptop with processor intel core i7 with turbo boost up to 2:7 ghz 8gb rams and gpu NVIDIA GeForce GT 740M (2 GB DDR3 dedicated) i want to know in approximation how fast ( in word/sec) can this computer crack a wpa password in bruteforce attack using airecrack-ng tools before i get linux kali and try cracking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It mostly depends on the password length.

In a tradeoff you can [download WPA Tables](http://www.renderlab.net/projects/WPA-tables/) to crack the PSK faster, if it is in the dictionary used to create the tables.